# Using enumerate function in while loops

Tags: python, loops, count

I have several mathematical algorithms that use iteration to search for the right answer. Here is one example:

```
def Bolzano(fonction, a, b, tol=0.000001):
    while abs(b - a) > tol:
        m = (a + b) / 2
        if sign(fonction(m)) == sign(fonction(a)):
            a = m
        else:
            b = m
    return a, b
```

I want to count how many times the algorithm goes through the loop to get *a* and *b*. However this is not a `for` function and it isn't a list, so I can't clearly indicate what objects do I want to count if I use `enumerate`. Is there a way to count those loops?

Note: I am not trying to change the code itself. I am really searching for a way to count iterations in a `while` loop, which I can then use for other cases.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The simplest answer if you need a counter outside of a `for` loop is to count manually using a simple variable and addition inside your `while` loop:

```
count = 0
while condition:
    ...
    count += 1
```

There is an alternative case - if each step of your iteration has a meanigful value to `yield`, you may want your loop to be a [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1756156/722121), and then use `for` loop and `enumerate()`. This makes most sense where you care about which step you are on, not just the count at the end. E.g:

```
def produce_steps():
    while condition:
        ...
        yield step_value

for count, step_value in enumerate(produce_steps()):
    ...
```

Answer (score 9):

For a counter I use `count` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import count
c = count(1)
>>>next(c)
1
>>>next(c)
2
```

and so on...

**Syntax**

```
count(start=0, step=1)
```

**Docs**

> Make an iterator that returns evenly spaced values starting with
>   number start.

Ref. [itertools.count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)

Comment: Using `count()` without a `for` loop doesn't really buy you anything, it just obscures your code a little. You just get a counter where you can't inspect the current value.