# While loop with enumeration in Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, iterator, generator

I sometimes have this:

```
i = 0
while condition:
    ...
    i += 1
```

Here is an example situation: [Create file but if name exists add number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852700/create-file-but-if-name-exists-add-number/61561245#61561245).

I don't know any option to do another way (except those discussed in [Using enumerate function in while loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576733/using-enumerate-function-in-while-loops)), but usually Python always has some syntactic sugar to avoid the manual "`i = 0, ..., i += 1` pattern".

Is there an alternative in newest versions of Python? Something like (pseudo-code):

```
for i in enumerate(while(condition)):
    ...
```

Comment: There's probably a better approach to this overall…?! E.g.: `glob` all existing file names, sort them, pick the one with the highest number, split it, use the number + 1.

Comment: Did you mean: `for i in count():`?

Comment: [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) is probably what you're looking for. `it = count()` `next(it)`

Comment: @deceze Yes there's probably a better approach, but it was just an easy example of while + enumeration.

Comment: @deceze I finally found an interesting solution with `enumerate`, a bit similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67265142 but slightly different, can we reopen this question?

Comment: @deceze The context makes that it doesn't really apply to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884213/looping-from-1-to-infinity-in-python but it might work here. Can I post? (community wiki is ok)